# Date column won't format correctly in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date column in Excel that looks like this:

```
1-23-2015
1-26-2015
1-29-2015
1-30-2015
02/02/2015
02/03/2015
02/04/2015
02/05/2015
02/06/2015
02/09/2015
02/10/2015
02/11/2015
02/12/2015
2-13-2015
2-17-2015
2-18-2015
2-19-2015
2-20-2015
2-23-2015
2-24-2015
2-25-2015
2-26-2015
2-27-2015
```

The column contains data in both text+date type
how do I convert the data to date type?

I need all the dates in format,

```
01-23-2015
01-26-2015
01-29-2015
01-30-2015
02/02/2015
02/03/2015
02/04/2015
02/05/2015
02/06/2015
02/09/2015
02/10/2015
02/11/2015
02/12/2015
```

I have tried with date formats, the first few dates just won't change to 01/23/2015 format. Is there any way I could change the dates in the required format?

Comment: What is your desired output? All dates in format MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: Yes, I want all dates in MM/DD/YYYY format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select column and go `Data > TextToColumns > Delimited > Next > Next` and choose an import date format of YMD (in your case MDY) `> Finish`

**IF** further changes are required:
Set the formatting of the column via `right-click > Format Cells > Number Tab > Custom` and type "YYYYMM" or whatever you need.